# git add . (dot) doesn't obey .gitignore (or my patterns are wrong)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, git-submodules, gitignore

I have the following situation.  In my asp.net webforms projects, I have some shared repositories that I optionally use *under* my main repositories.  The folders are named *Shared* and then *Shared.** for others.  For example, I have a folder structure like this.

```
\main  
.. \\.git  
.. \main-subfolder  

.. \Shared (this should be ignored since own repo)  
.... \\.git  
.... \Shared-subfolder  
.... shared files  

.. main-files
```

I think this pattern I'm using might be similar to git sub-modules, but that is (hopefully) reserved for another discussion.

My .gitignore file originally simply had: `Shared*/` and everything worked great.

Then I discovered that in my asp mvc projects, my *Views/Shared* folders were getting ignored (as expected given the above pattern).  So I tried to add an exclusion with `!Views/Shared/` but that didn't work in that git still didn't detect that for the mvc projects it should be adding *Views/Shared* content.

So I ended up with:

```
Shared*/*
!Views/Shared/
```

And all seemed to work, however, I detected a problem in my original webforms projects (that should be ignoring folders of *Shared**).  So the following image.  `git status` appears to correctly be ignoring the Shared folder, but when I do a `git add .` then `git status`, you can see that it has been added.

[image: git add . workflow]

Note: `git com -am "Commit Message"` appears to work too.  If that would have been my original step instead of `git add .`, the *Shared* folder is ignored on the commit.

Is my setup (nested repository) not supported or is my .gitignore pattern incorrect?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid confusion, please use the standard Git verbs (e.g. `commit` instead of `com`, `status` instead of `st`) in your question; at the very least, explain what each of your aliases stands for.

Comment: Sorry.  Muscle memory, but you've deduced what they were, so leaving image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confused even when I reproduced what you're looking at.  My sympathies. Some of what git's doing here caters to abstruse usage (and should arguably not be its default behavior), and the pathname anchoring is just quirky.

tl;dr, from comments and examples, I think you want:

```
Shared*/
!**/Views/Shared*/
```

---

So, the confusing bits:

`git status` by default (`-u normal`) chooses what (unignored and)  untracked directories to show based on whether there are any *files* in them  you could `git add` without forcing -- which isn't the same thing as checking whether there are any untracked submodules in there. It's sometimes useful to bypass untracked submodule boundaries, but an unadorned `git status` report doesn't look to me like a good place to do it by default.

Second, git's pattern matching requires a leading `/` to anchor plain names at the pattern root (`.gitignore` location or top-of-worktree for other sources), but paths with an embedded `/` are always anchored at the pattern root, so to exclude a multipart path pattern anywhere, prefix it with `**/`.  I'd hate to have to argue with anyone insisting this violates the principle of least surprise ...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll read your rant and see if I can grasp sub-modules after that.

Comment: Tried to put a line feed, but to respond to your comments...a) Those two lines in my .gitignore are last two in the file so should be safe regarding 'conflicts', b) yes, my status said Shared was a file but it was not.  It was indeed a directory that contained a .git repository.  I could append a screen shot if you'd like, but I did notice this and was surprised, but ignored it and didn't comment on it on the original post.  Let me know if you have any other ideas or if you still think your recommended change is worth testing.

Comment: I think the change is worth testing. Git ordinarily doesn't examine what's in submodules at all (whether you've hooked them up to the `git submodule` convenience machinery or not). I see status does report submodules as files, never noticed that before.

Comment: So this doesn't appear to work.  a) It seems to still ignore \Shared nested repos (good) b) If I already had Views\Shared in my repo, and I add a file, it detects that (good).  c) If I have a file named SharedSecrets.txt, it ignores this (bad - anyway to make Shared pattern only do dirs?) d) If I didn't have a Views\Shared in my repo and I created that new folder structure, git add . and git st both continue to ignore it (bad).  Thanks for help thus far.

Comment: Any chance of access to a content-free extract of your repo? ... hunh.  That'd be a good tool.  Anyway, if you can do it it looks to me like that could save many round trips.

Comment: I don't know how to do a content free extract, but you can just make an empty repo right?  And add folders as we've been experimenting with.  That's what I've been doing to test.  Let me know.  I'm still searching internet for samples to see if there is a better pattern for this.

Comment: What I mean is, it'd be easiest if I could see what you're looking at, without anything proprietary, but including enough of the worktree to reproduce what's going wrong.  I set up what I believe is the situation you describe and git doesn't behave that way, so there's some miscommunication going on here somewhere.

Comment: Do you have a github or bitbucket account?  How should I get a folder structure to you?

Comment: Just put it on your own and post the link.

Comment: I just threw it out in my public dropbox.  In its current state, if you do a status on GitIgnore folder, it shows one file will go in.  But if you do a git add ., you'll see that the Shared folder goes in as well.  Here is link:  Will remove once we resolve - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13354075/GitIgnore.zip

Comment: Your `.gitignore` doesn't have a `Shared*/` line in it, only a `Shared*/*`.  Your `Shared` is a nested repository, a submodule. Ordinarily, there's no difference between the two ignore specs above, but for submodules there is: what gets added from submodules isn't a path, it's the HEAD commit's id.  To ignore a submodule, you have to ignore its directory, not the files inside.

Comment: I didn't create the repo 'complex' enough.  I've updated dropbox zip.  I created one commit.  Then I added a file under Specification\Views\Shared folder.  If you do a git `status` with `Shared*/` it says the repo is clean.  If you use the `Status*/*` it (correctly) says that new file is going to be added.  Note that with your `Shared*/`, it did correctly detect files in `Views/Shared` if that was at the root of the repo.  Is my exclusion of `!Views/Shared/` supposed to have a * at the front?  Note, I did mention this behavior in original post (although I hadn't detected the root dir behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the examples, the 1st one's .gitignore and the 2nd's extra structure did it for me.  At least I think so -- I hope the answer's sensible here now.